# Does Rylai's Crystal Scepter trigger on Teemo's Toxic Shot?

Tags: league-of-legends

In *League of Legends* if I had a Rylai's Crystal Scepter (which has slow on spell hits as its passive) and I autoattack as Teemo, who has a magic DoT poison on hit, would it apply the passive slow from Rylai's Crystal Scepter?

Comment: the slow from your Blinding shot would still work, but if you want to have teemo's basic attacks slow enemies you'll need a frozen mallet.

Answer (score 7):

No. Teemo's toxic shot cannot proc Rylai's Crystal Scepter, as it is an on-hit effect. In general, on-hit effects do not trigger item abilities or spell vamp.

Other DoTs (which are not on-hit effects), however, *do* trigger the Rylai's slow, like Mordekaiser's Ultimate, and Malzahar's Malefic Visions.

Comment: and Teemo's mushrooms?

Comment: @AaronBrown Exactly!